# How to disable multiple instances of cursors in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

**Environment**

Sublime Text:  3.1.1, Build 3176
Windows 10

**Undesired Behaviour**

I must have unintentionally pressed a keyboard combination as I have not had this issue before.

I cannot identify what circumstances create the undesired behavior, but sometimes this happens:

[image]

ie, I will be editing some text and realise that the cursor is in 2 (possibly more?) places and everything i am typing is also appearing in multiple places.

*Edit:  It seems to sometimes occurs after I have `Ctrl + V / Ctrl + Shift + V` pasted content.*

**What I've Tried**

I've looked at this link, as the title sounded like it might be related:

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

But on closer reading it doesn't seem to be.

I think the following answer might explain the behaviour, but not how to disable it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46800245

**Desired Behaviour**

I'd like to know how to disable the undesired behaviour.

Comment: Its an extremely useful feature, activated by using a combination of SHIFT/CTRL+ALT and arrow UP/DOWN. The exact combination depends on the OS that sublimetext is run on. I'd recommend getting used to the feature (not activate it by accident) instead of disabling it. If you happen to activate it by accident, hit ESC to remove all but the original cursor.
To disable it you will need to find the hotkey-combination in sublimetext's preferences file and remove the entry or change the keys to something else.

Comment: Thanks, by any chance do you know what the feature is specifically called?   I am looking at the following link and `Ctrl + ⇧ + ↑` refers to `Move line/selection up` whilst `Ctrl + Alt + Up` refers to `Column selection up` - they don't *seem* to be related to the behaviour I am describing:  http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html

Comment: I dont have any windows machine right now, only a mac. Looking at your link (windows keybindings) I dont find the multi-cursor option. However looking at the mac-keybindings, the options are listed as "Extra cursor on the line above/below" (⌃ + ⇧ + ↑).

Comment: There are many ways to get multiple selections; using the key sequence referenced above, using `Ctrl+D`, using a snippet, etc. Generally speaking there's probably no good way to block them all (and you lose features if you do).

Comment: press on shift + alt and click somewhere in the editor. tada.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Cursors on Sublime3, is activated by default either with 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse button</kbd>
or by
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>

## disabling <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>:

setting is called <kbd>split_selection_into_lines</kbd>. to disable it (Windows):
click <kbd>Preferences</kbd>, <kbd>Key Binding</kbd>, and on the file <kbd>Default (Windows).sublime-keymap</kbd> that will open add the line. (

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+l"], "command": "" },
```

be sure to put this inside the default brackets [ ].
Same is for Linux or Mac, only thing changes is the operating system name on the filename.

## disabling <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse button</kbd>:

Windows - create <kbd>Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap</kbd> in <kbd>%appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User</kbd>

Linux - create <kbd>Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap</kbd> in <kbd>~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User</kbd>

Mac - create <kbd>Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap</kbd> in <kbd>~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User</kbd>

open it with a text editor and paste the following lines in it:

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "",
        "command": ""
    }
]
```

Save and you are done. In my test, (win10, sublime text 3) method worked instantly, without even restarting Sublime Text 3.

Comment: If you have copied this from somewhere please correctly cite.

Comment: @Yunnosch is original research, I have combined several sources, that I don't recall now. I needed to solve it for my self.

Comment: In that case impressive. Please understand that I cannot technically judge and hence cannot vote. Good luck.